# Using variables in .bat files

Tags: batch-file

I'd like to use a variable in a batch file. However, when I use `TEST_TIME_IN_SECONDS` in the command below I get an error. Replacing `%TEST_TIME_IN_SECONDS%` with a integer works, so it must be a syntax problem.

```
Set TEST_TIME_IN_SECONDS = 10800

ScalabilityTester.exe -t 50 -dc "dsn=..." -q "SELECT..." -tt %TEST_TIME_IN_SECONDS% -o "...output"
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Change your line to read

```
Set TEST_TIME_IN_SECONDS=10800
```